# Put a quote in a HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

example,

```
<span class="hotspot" 
    onmouseover="tooltip.show('<table id=\"test\"><tr><th>123</th></tr><tr><th>123</th></tr></table>');" 
    onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">porttitor orci</span>
```

in here, i'm trying to add id attribute in table tag, but i already used "" and '', so something is messed up and not working.

Any good solution?

Comment: That has nothing to do with "you already used it" (don't even know what exactly you are trying to say with that). You have to HTML-escape the `"` like this: `&quot;` or `&#34;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<span class="hotspot" 
    onmouseover="tooltip.show('<table id=&quot;test&quot;><tr><th>123</th></tr><tr><th>123</th></tr></table>');" 
    onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">porttitor orci</span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WYnD/)

Answer (score 1):

In an attribute value that is delimited by Ascii quotation marks ("), you can present the Ascii quotation mark itself using the reference `&quot;`.

However, there is usually a better way. In the given case, you can simply omit the quotation marks, since `id=test` works just fine (unless you are using XHTML served with an XML content type, and most probably you aren’t).